# Reference request: Quotient of quadratic forms

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, divisibility, quadratic-forms

Is there a way to determine if there exist integers x and y that, when plugged into two quadratic forms $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$, their quotient will also be an integer (i.e., $P \equiv 0 \pmod{Q}$)? I've found a reference that establishes a [Hasse principle for the division of quadratic forms](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jmath1948/31/1/31_1_141/_article/-char/ja/), but I haven't found any further sources or examples.

Comment: Some potential reductions: * first check $y=0$, then set $t=x/y$ to reduce it to a quotient of two quadratic polynomials in one rational variable; * do a change of variables to write the denominator as $t^2+c$ for some rational $c$; * long divide to write the quotient as $q + (ax+b)/(t^2+c)$ (all parameters rational); * at this point I think there are only finitely many denominators for $t$ that could result in an integer value. // One could also look into calculating the resultant of the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the difference $P - nQ$  to have a square discriminant  for some integer $n.$ Then it is isotropic, there is a (primitive) pair $(x,y)$  that makes it zero, because it factors as the product of two linear forms.

If $P(x,y) = a x^2 + b xy + c y^2$  while $Q(x,y) = d x^2 + e xy + f y^2,$  the discriminant is
$$ \Delta =  (b - ne)^2 - 4(a - nd)(c - nf)    $$
or
$$ \Delta = (e^2 - 4 df) n^2 +  (4af + 4cd -2be)n +(b^2 -4ac).$$  And you want an $n$  for which the thing is square (including zero)  as in

$$ m^2 = (e^2 - 4 df) n^2 +  (4af + 4cd -2be)n +(b^2 -4ac).$$

This is not going to be possible if the right hand side is always negative, which might happen if both $P,Q$  are positive definite  and the mixed term is of modest absolute value.

Worth trying some example pairs $P,Q$

Comment: A natural example is $\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}$, which corresponds to the trigonometric function $\cos(2\phi)$. When we calculate the discriminant, we get $m^2=-4n^2+4$. This equation has integer solutions when $n=0$ and $n=\pm1$, consistent with the trigonometric interpretation. Nice!